Question on Counting Different Multinomial Coefficients in an Expansion
As a non-mathematician, I’d like to ask a question regarding the multinomial theorem. I apologize in advance if my terminology isn’t precise, and I hope my question is clear enough.
I'm trying to find the number of distinct multinomial coefficients in expansions of expressions like $$(a+b+c)^3$$ $$(a+b+c+d)^4$$ and so on. My interest is focused on simple expansions, such as cases where there are three terms raised to the power of 3, four terms to the power of 4, five terms to the power of 5, and so on. I’m not dealing with more complex scenarios.
For example; expansion of $$(a+b+c)^3$$ yields:
$$1a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+1b^3+3a^2c+6abc+3b^2c+3ac^2+3bc^2+1c^3$$
where we see three distinct multinomial coefficients: 1, 3, and 6.
Similarly, in $$(a+b+c+d)^4$$ I manually counted five distinct coefficients: 1, 4, 6, 12, and 24.
And for $$(a+b+c+d+e)^5$$ there seem to be seven distinct coefficients: 1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 60, and 120.
My question is: Is there a formula or method to determine the number of distinct multinomial coefficients for any expansion, such as 6 terms to the power of 6, 7 to the power of 7... or 18 to the power of 18. Thank you for your time and help! I hope I’ve managed to express my question clearly.

Welcome on MSE. Your sequence corresponds to the sequence A070289 on the OEIS (https://oeis.org/A070289).

As mentioned in my comment the number $b_n$ of distinct multinomial coefficients in $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^n$$
is given by the sequence A070289 on the OEIS. For example, for $n=6$ you get $b_6=11$ distinct multinomial coefficients, $b_7=14$ and $b_{18}=243$. The main reference "On the number of distinct multinomial coefficients" by Andrews, Knopfmacher, and Zimmermann gives some estimates thanks to algebraic methods.

Thanks for fast and correct solution

You're welcome, don't forget to upvote it if you find it useful.
